# What exactly is "pattern matching"?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I know some examples of "pattern matching". E.g. in the context of functional programming, and regular expressions.

But is there a precise definition?

In particular, it seems that it has to do with whether a finite automaton can recognize it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition

Comment: Pattern matching doesn't require an underlaying finite automaton. For example, Lua has pattern matching that works using [PEGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar), which are strictly more powerful than regular expressions.